# what is Orbited?

Tags: comet, xmpp, websocket, dwr

from my understanding obited can do both comet and xmpp ? it is better than using typical comet library dwr right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbited is a library to create 'realtime' applications that run in a web browser (it implements a technique known as *Comet*). More specifically is provides code and strategies to implement *many* protocols (xmpp, irc, stomp, amqp, etc) on top of what is known as a "web socket" - an object that abstracts away the many peculiarities of actually implementing *Comet*. Furthermore, Orbited describes, and in some cases provides, the back-end components (asynchronous webservers) that need to know and work with the front-end Comet clients.

Here is a little more detail on Comet and how Orbited plays in:

> What makes Comet more complex to
>   implement (than making an Ajax app,
>   say), is that you need both the client
>   (a Comet javascript client) and the
>   server (an asynchronous webserver like
>   Twisted) working in conjunction, and
>   this is what you get with Orbited -
>   both the javascript client and the
>   server.